# Get enum value from string constructor

Tags: java, enums

In Java, I am trying to get the enum value from a string.

For example I got:

`MESSENGERINIT("@L")`

This is in the enum as well:

```
private String header;

private ServerPackets(String header) 
{
    this.header = header;
}

public String getHeader()
{
    return this.header;
    //more code here.
}
```

But if I try to use:

```
System.out.println("[" + ServerPackets.valueOf(header) + 
    "] - Received unregistered header " + 
    Base64Encoding.decode(header) + "(" + header + ") with body " + 
    connection.reader.toString());
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant 
com.kultakala.communication.ServerPackets.@L
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)</code>
```

What does the error message mean and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enum.valueof(String)` uses the name of the enumerator -- MESSENGERINIT -- not the string you passed to the constructor.

If you want to map other strings to the enumerators, consider creating a static map in the enumerator class.

For example:

```
enum ServerPackets {
...

private static Map<String,ServerPackets> s_map = new HashMap<String,ServerPackets>();
static {
    map.put( "@L", MESSENGERINIT);
    ...
}
public ServerPackets getEnumFromHeader( String header ) {
   return map.get( header );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the name of the enum value by the string of the constructor?

Comment: +1 You could create a static `fromString(String s)` method that iterates over `ServerPackets.values()` and returns the matching enum (if found).

Comment: Don't forget the `enum.valueOf(String)` method.

Comment: JoshuaBakker - See edit above. Axel's linear approach may also be appropriate. @OldCurmudgeon - that's being used in the question.